# Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() doesn't return the correct directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC server, I want to add a folder to store static files. I found the following code to perform that:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "StaticFiles")),
    RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
});
```

In my computer, the project is located in `"C:\Users\MyUsername\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1"`, in the same directory there is a folder called "StaticFiles" and a `Startup.cs` file where the code above is written.

But when I execute the code I got the following error:

```
'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' in Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll C:\Program Files\IIS Express\StaticFiles\
```

The `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` is returning `"C:\\Program Files\\IIS Express"` instead of `"C:\Users\MyUsername\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1"`. **How can I get the correct direction?**

Comment: Hi :) If you want it to be the route where the application sits, change from IIS Express to "YourProjectName" when debugging

Comment: I think that you should include all files from StaticFiles folder in your project and set BuildAction to `Content` in Properties for all of them. That way they will be included in installation file.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović `StaticFiles` is inside the project folder. What do you mean with `BuildAction `? My Visual Studio is in Spanish, I didn't find any similar button, where is supposed to be that button?

Comment: Right-click a file, then click `Properties`.

Comment: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` can change as a program runs - it should **not** be used to find files relative to the location of an application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in **ASP.NET Core 2.2** which has been reported in [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4206) and Microsoft ASP.NET Core team has provided a solution as follows and they will add this solution to the feature release of ASP.NET Core.

Write a helper class as follows:

```
public class CurrentDirectoryHelpers
{
    internal const string AspNetCoreModuleDll = "aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll";

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(AspNetCoreModuleDll)]
    private static extern int http_get_application_properties(ref IISConfigurationData iiConfigData);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct IISConfigurationData
    {
        public IntPtr pNativeApplication;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public string pwzFullApplicationPath;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public string pwzVirtualApplicationPath;
        public bool fWindowsAuthEnabled;
        public bool fBasicAuthEnabled;
        public bool fAnonymousAuthEnable;
    }

    public static void SetCurrentDirectory()
    {
        try
        {
            // Check if physical path was provided by ANCM
            var sitePhysicalPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_IIS_PHYSICAL_PATH");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sitePhysicalPath))
            {
                // Skip if not running ANCM InProcess
                if (GetModuleHandle(AspNetCoreModuleDll) == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    return;
                }

                IISConfigurationData configurationData = default(IISConfigurationData);
                if (http_get_application_properties(ref configurationData) != 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                sitePhysicalPath = configurationData.pwzFullApplicationPath;
            }

            Environment.CurrentDirectory = sitePhysicalPath;
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
```

Then call the `SetCurrentDirectory()` method in your code as follows:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(

        CurrentDirectoryHelpers.SetCurrentDirectory(); // call it here

        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "StaticFiles")),
    RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
});
```

Now everything should work fine!

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to sound pessimistic, but, what advantage has your code over [Jonas Tuemand Møller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508954/7655838) answers. His codes works and only has 1 line. Your code has... a few more lines. Anyway, mjwills has stated in comments on my question, that in no circumstance `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` should be used to get the path since it can change as the program runs. But thanks for pointing about the bug.

Comment: @EnderLook may be `Jonas Tuemand Møller` approach would not work while you are using `InProcess` hosting model in `ASP.NET Core 2.2`. So safest way to use this solution as Microsoft ASP.NET Core suggest this.

Comment: Ok, I don't have any idea what is `InProcess` but sounds important :). I use this. Thanks! (I don't accept it yet because it's common practice wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer).

Comment: Haha! :) No problem! another  point to be noted that it will work in debug mode without adding this `<ItemGroup><Content Include="StaticFiles\**"><CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory></Content></ItemGroup>` in the .csproj file

Comment: I know, but I noticed that VS doesn't copy the "StaticFiles" (nor its content) in the release version when I press "publish". By trial an error I found that adding that line to `.csproj` the folder was copied to the release.

Comment: Oh! yes! For publish you have to add this.

Comment: This is overkill for the OP's situation. Jonas's answer is all you need here.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks but in case of `InProcess` hosting model will `IHostingEnvironment env` be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, it will. `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` will be set correctly regardless of the hosting model being used.

Comment: Okay! I shall a check!

Comment: Isn't OutOfProcess the default, with InProcess as an opt-in? Obviously the OP has it configured as such that it's going InProcess (hence the IIS paths), just wondering in case it's relevant

Comment: Sorry, what? @TanvirArjel. So, what must I use? `CurrentDirectoryHelpers` or `IHostingEnvironment env; env.ContentRootPath`?

Comment: It's now your choice! Which best suits you? 

Answer (score 4):

The IHostingEnvironment interface provides information about the environment including the base path. You can get an instance using dependency injection.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // env.ContentRootPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that default working directory of your application is pointing to *Working Directory of IIS Express*

First Try setting **Base Path** from `Program.cs` using `HostingEnvironment`

```
  var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
```

If this does not work, the easiest option is to set the working directory of your IIS Express launch profile from `launchSettings.json`. For this,

- Right click on your project and select properties.
- Go under Debug
- Select the profile that is going to be used
- Go under `Working Directory` text box and set your working directory

Note: This does not affect your builds, It is just a debug configuration.

---

```
new HostBuilder()
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
    {               
         builder
            .SetBasePath(context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
```

Comment: `env` doesn't exist, what do you mean with that? Also, I am currently using `CreateDefaultBuilder()`, can I use `SetBasePath` on it?

Comment: please check my edit