# Received a DirectoryNotFoundException: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Static_Files When application was moved to a live server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an application that utilizes a directory of static files outside of wwwroot. Thus, I created a new middleware for this folder in the Startup.cs file. It works locally however, when put into production the folder can't be found even though it is in the project.

I have added error checks to my Program.cs file. It seems to be coming from the new StaticOptions middleware I created. However, I think this might be an issue with asp.net core 2.2

**Startup.cs**

```
 app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Static_Files")),
                RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
            });
```

**Error**

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Static_Files\
```

The directory can't be found even though it is there.

Comment: Check if the directory have the application pool user/group

Comment: you using '/Static_Files' and '/StaticFiles'

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding the Static_Files and StaticFiles are renaming the path to the directory. The directory is in my application is I don't think itsa ppl user/group issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in ASP.NET Core 2.2 which has been reported in [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4206) and Microsoft ASP.NET Core team has provided a solution as follows.

Add the following class somewhere in your application. This code comes [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module/samples_snapshot/2.x/CurrentDirectoryHelpers.cs).

```
internal class CurrentDirectoryHelpers
{
    internal const string AspNetCoreModuleDll = "aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll";

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(AspNetCoreModuleDll)]
    private static extern int http_get_application_properties(ref IISConfigurationData iiConfigData);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct IISConfigurationData
    {
        public IntPtr pNativeApplication;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public string pwzFullApplicationPath;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        public string pwzVirtualApplicationPath;
        public bool fWindowsAuthEnabled;
        public bool fBasicAuthEnabled;
        public bool fAnonymousAuthEnable;
    }

    public static void SetCurrentDirectory()
    {
        try
        {
            // Check if physical path was provided by ANCM
            var sitePhysicalPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_IIS_PHYSICAL_PATH");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sitePhysicalPath))
            {
                // Skip if not running ANCM InProcess
                if (GetModuleHandle(AspNetCoreModuleDll) == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    return;
                }

                IISConfigurationData configurationData = default(IISConfigurationData);
                if (http_get_application_properties(ref configurationData) != 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                sitePhysicalPath = configurationData.pwzFullApplicationPath;
            }

            Environment.CurrentDirectory = sitePhysicalPath;
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in the **Main** function of the **Program** class add the following line as the first thing in the function.

```
CurrentDirectoryHelpers.SetCurrentDirectory();
```

Relevant reference links :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54509770/10201850

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/9865